# How to recognize the first loop call in if statement?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have code in template:

```
{% for p in products %}
    {% if p.parent == None %}
        <li class="{% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}">
            {{ p.name|upper }}
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

In my case class "active" shows me in li with parent != None. I can't use [...]filter(parent=None) in view as I must have a complete list of products.

The problem is that if first object.parent in products `=! None` Django will think that the first iteration happened so that I will never add `active` to my class.
So I want to check when the first iteration with successful `if` statement happened. Any ways to do this?

Comment: Why do you have `==` in your template if you need `!=`?

Comment: I need ==, I must show only main products

Comment: could you use {% if not p.parent %}?  Usually if an element is None, it will register as false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could recover the first element in the view in python, add it to the context and then test in your template :

```
{% for p in products %}
    {% if not p.parent %}
        <li class="{% if p == first_element %}active{% endif %}">
            {{ p.name|upper }}
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: +1 for recommending the processing be done in the view. Django says all over the place that templates are intentionally dumb and processing should be done in the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% with is_first=True %}
{% for p in products %}
    {% if p.parent == None %}
        <li class="{% if is_first %}active{% endwith % }{% endif %}">
            {{ p.name|upper }}
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Can not test now - but perhaps that work!

Answer (score 0):

You can put this on the objects themselves or as extra variable, when you build the context. Do code like this:

e.g. instead of:

```
ctx['products'] = Product.objects.all()
```

do something like this:

```
ctx['products'] = list(Product.objects.all())
   is_first = True
   for p in ctx['products']:
      p.is_active = p.parent is None and is_first:
      is_first = False
```

Then in the template, just do:

```
<li class="{% if p.is_active %}active{% endif %}">
    {{ p.name|upper }}
</li>
```

If you don't want to write on the object, use extra variable

```
ctx['products'] = list(Product.objects.all())
   is_first = True
   for p in ctx['products']:
      if p.parent is None and is_first: 
          ctx['active_id'] = p.id
          break
```

Then in the template, just do:

```
<li class="{% if p.id == active_id %}active{% endif %}">
    {{ p.name|upper }}
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use forloop.counter like this

```
{% for p in products %}
    {% if forloop.counter == 0 %}
        <li class="{% if is_first %}active{% endwith % }{% endif %}">
            {{ p.name|upper }}
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```